# MS Access Form Sidebar Menu Animation

Tags: ms-access, vba, side-menu

I've been trying to create sort of a sidebar menu that would pop in when you click on a button for quite a bit now and for some reason, I am unable to do it. When I save the code and open the form to test, the "side menu" (which is another form) can be seen instead of being out of the area that you can see. [Imgur preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQUIX.jpg).

The list of forms is pretty messy, but the only ones actually used in the question are the "Menu" and "TestFormFormForm" (don't ask about the name). The code I am using is as follows.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0
    Do
        DoEvents
        Menu.Left = Menu.Left - 100
        timeout (0.0075)
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = 50
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.ScrollBars = 0
    Menu.Left = Me.Width + 1000
    Menu.Move _
        Left:=Me.Width + 1000, Top:=500
End Sub

Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub
```

I have also tried using Me.WindowWidth = XYZ until I realized that WindowWidth is read-only.

Comment: Not clear to me what the issue is. What do you mean by 'out of the area'? A subform must be placed within the dimensions of main form. Exactly what in your code is failing? What happens - error message, wrong results, nothing?

Comment: I think a video my describe it better. What i am trying to achieve (similar) https://imgur.com/a/sJeZ9 - This is the current result https://youtu.be/e4cd0nX8Xqw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works for me:

1. set database option for Overlapping Windows
2. set the main form AutoResize property to No and sized so the right edge covers part of the right edge of the subform to account for vertical scroll bar space
3. set ScrollBars property to neither
4. set the subform width as small as possible (must be at least width of its controls) and Visible property to No
5. eliminate form Load event
6. use Toggle instead of Command button
7. experiment with various combinations of constants in code

Revised code:

```
Private Sub Toggle4_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Me.Menu.Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents
        Me.Menu.Width = Me.Menu.Width + IIf(Me.Toggle4, 200, -200)
        Me.Menu.Left = Me.Menu.Left - IIf(Me.Toggle4, 200, -200)
        Me.Toggle4.Left = Me.Toggle4.Left - IIf(Me.Toggle4, 200, -200)
        timeout (0.01)
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = 10
    Me.Menu.Visible = Me.Toggle4
End Sub
```

Comment: That certainly is a good idea and a pretty nice approach. Though, is it normal that the toggle blinks while the menu is opening?

Comment: No blinking here.

Comment: Maybe it is because of me trying to move the toggle along with the side menu itself. [Preview](https://youtu.be/sGPJu3Y-HGU) - If you pay attention, the toggle gets hidden when the menu is closing and it blinks while the animation is played (blinks, as in, feels like it changes the color to the default one).

Comment: Added code to move the button. Mostly smooth movement and blinking hardly noticeable. Seems to depend on speed (the timeout value). The button is not hidden by the form. See my revised code.